# Why ArcTan[1, 0. I ] yields -1.5708+0. I?

Tags: bugs, numerics, complex, trigonometry

**Bug introduced in 5.2 or earlier and persisting through 12.0.0**

---

Why `ArcTan[1, 0. I ]`  yields `-1.5708+0. I` ?
The result should equal to `0`.

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: it does look like a bug. For a work around use exact zero `ArcTan[1, 0*I]` instead of non-exact zero `ArcTan[1, 0.*I]`

Comment: Please don't add [bugs] tag until the community or WRI has confirmed it. Then, I'm not familiar with this topic, but can it be related to branch cut and so on?

Comment: @Nasser The original expression I calculated is like `ArcTan[1, p q]`, where `p` is a MachinePrecision complex number and `q` is a real number. Let `q` be `0`,  it yeilds `-1.5708+0. I`,  but it should be `0`.  And then I found this is because the result of `ArcTan[1, 0. I ]` is `-1.5708+0. I` during the calculation.

Comment: @xzczd I have tried to plot `Re[ArcTan[1, (x + I y)]]` and `Im[ArcTan[1, (x + I y)]]` in xy plane, and there is no branch cut near x=0 and y=0.

Comment: (1) The docs "define" `ArcTan[x,y]` in terms of quadrants, implying real arguments, but also give a formula valid for complex numbers, `-I Log[(x + I y)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]`. (2) The [MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-v-atan2) seems to define `atan2` only for reals. So maybe WRI botched the implementation.  The second argument `0. I` seems to be a special case, since any small nonzero number yields a correct value.

Comment: I added the bugs tag.  There seems to be consensus (at least no dissent).  Please report it to Wolfram Research.

Comment: A very old bug, I obtain the same incorrect value for ArcTan[1, 0. I ] using Mathematica 5.2 and 8.0.4 on Win7x64.

Comment: Bug still present in MMA 12.1

Answer (score 8):

It looks like a bug.

Perhaps

```
ArcTan[1, p q + $MinMachineNumber * I]
```

will be acceptable.  The little noise is unlikely to be a numerical problem. The main pitfall is when `p q == -$MinMachineNumber * I`, which drops you back into the buggy case.

```
ArcTan[1. + 0. I, $MinMachineNumber*I]
(*  0. + 0. I  *)
```

**Update: Runtime environments for existing code**

You can overload `ArcTan` with code like this:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{ArcTan},
 Unprotect[ArcTan];
 ArcTan[x_, y_] := func[x, y];
 Protect[ArcTan];
 ArcTan[1., 0. I]
 ]
```

There are several issues with doing this, and the simplest thing to do is to understand your particular use-case and choose an appropriate compromise.

For instance, here is one possibility:

```
ClearAll[runWithNewArcTan];
SetAttributes[runWithNewArcTan, HoldAll];
runWithNewArcTan[code_] :=
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{ArcTan},
   Unprotect[ArcTan];

   (* keeps packed arrays from being unpacked *)
   ClearAttributes[ArcTan, Listable];

   (* makes all ArcTan[x,y] results Complex;
    * vectorized formula means it still works on lists
    * however, the formula can have rounding errors when y == 0
    * of around $MachineEpsilon in magnitude *)
   ArcTan[x_, y_] /; ! FreeQ[{x, y}, _Complex] :=
     -I Log[(x + I y)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]];

   Protect[ArcTan];

   (* run code *)
   code
   ];
```

Here is another:

```
ClearAll[runWithNewArcTan];
SetAttributes[runWithNewArcTan, HoldAll];
runWithNewArcTan[code_] :=
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{ArcTan},
   Unprotect[ArcTan];
   (* keeping Listable attribute means packed arrays will be unpacked *)

   (* fix just the buggy values; the patterns tests are not
    * vectorized, so the Listable attribute will unpack packed arrays
    * even when neither definition below is used. *)
   ArcTan[x_, y_] /; 
     Precision[{x, y}] === MachinePrecision && 
       ! FreeQ[{x, y}, _Complex] && Positive[x] && y == 0 := 0. + 0. I;
   ArcTan[x_, y_] /; 
     Precision[{x, y}] === MachinePrecision && 
       ! FreeQ[{x, y}, _Complex] && Negative[x] && y == 0 := Pi + 0. I;
   Protect[ArcTan];

   (* run code *)
   code
   ];
```

The last one would work well in `code` that does not use packed arrays.  I haven't thought of a simple way that would work exactly like `ArcTan[x, y]` but fix the bug.